# How to reset image to it's default size in openseadragon

Tags: angular, typescript, openseadragon

I am implementing openseadragon plugin in angular4 on a popup slider, on close of popup (or while going to next image) if current image is zoomed I have to resize current image to it's default size (similar to go home button).

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your OpenSeadragon Viewer is called `viewer`, you'd do `viewer.viewport.goHome()` to go back to the default size.

Comment: I tried with this initially, but it's not working.. :(

Comment: Is this right when the viewer loads? If so, you need to wait for the open event first. Otherwise, can you give me any more information about what you're doing, or share a repro?

Comment: My mistake, I am calling method from wrong component. It's working fine now, Thanks.